# Pandas generate columns from single column of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which goes like this:

```
index,labels
1,created the tower
2,destroyed the tower
3,created the swimming pool
4,destroyed the swimming pool
```

Now, if I pass the list of the columns I want in place of labels column (doesn't contain all the words in the label columns)

```
['created','tower','destroyed','swimming pool']
```

I want to obtain the dataframe as:

```
index,created,destroyed,tower,swimming pool
1,1,0,1,0
2,0,1,1,0
3,1,0,0,1
4,0,1,0,1
```

I looked into get_dummies, but that didnt help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `str.contains` in a loop.

```
print(df)

                        labels
0            created the tower
1          destroyed the tower
2    created the swimming pool
3  destroyed the swimming pool

req = ['created', 'destroyed', 'tower', 'swimming pool']

out = pd.concat([df['labels'].str.contains(x) for x in req], 1, keys=req).astype(int)
print(out)

   created  destroyed  tower  swimming pool
0        1          0      1              0
1        0          1      1              0
2        1          0      0              1
3        0          1      0              1
```

Comment: Nice one dude ~ :)

Comment: @Wen I'm not convinced it's the best... maybe you can think of something cooler?

Comment: I think It is good enough , The one I am using is `nltk`, Personally do not think the one I am using is better than your solution.

Comment: I compare the speed of yours and mine , Your solution is 3 times faster than the one I am using ..:-)

Answer (score 9):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'labels': ['created the tower', 'destroyed the tower', 'created the swimming pool', 'destroyed the swimming pool']})

columns = ['created','destroyed','tower','swimming pool']
pat = '|'.join(['({})'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in columns])
result = (df['labels'].str.extractall(pat)).groupby(level=0).count()
result.columns = columns
print(result)
```

yields

```
   created  destroyed  tower  swimming pool
0        1          0      1              0
1        0          1      1              0
2        1          0      0              1
3        0          1      0              1
```

---

Most of the work is done by `str.extractall`:

```
In [808]: df['labels'].str.extractall(r'(created)|(destroyed)|(tower)|(swimming pool)')
Out[808]: 
               0          1      2              3
  match                                          
0 0      created        NaN    NaN            NaN
  1          NaN        NaN  tower            NaN
1 0          NaN  destroyed    NaN            NaN
  1          NaN        NaN  tower            NaN
2 0      created        NaN    NaN            NaN
  1          NaN        NaN    NaN  swimming pool
3 0          NaN  destroyed    NaN            NaN
  1          NaN        NaN    NaN  swimming pool
```

Since each match is placed on its own row, the desired result can be obtained by doing a `groupby/count` operation where we group by the first level of the index (the original index).

---

Note that the Python `re` module has a hard-coded limit to the number of named groups allowed:

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/sre_compile.py in compile(p, flags)
    577     if p.pattern.groups > 100:
    578         raise AssertionError(
--> 579             "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
    580             )
    581 

AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups
```

**This limits the `extractall` approach used above to a maximum of 100 keywords**.

---

Here is a benchmark which suggests that cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution (at least for a certain range of use cases) may be the fastest:

```
In [76]: %timeit using_contains(ser, keywords)
10 loops, best of 3: 63.4 ms per loop

In [77]: %timeit using_defchararray(ser, keywords)
10 loops, best of 3: 90.6 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit using_extractall(ser, keywords)
10 loops, best of 3: 126 ms per loop
```

Here is the setup I used:

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def using_defchararray(ser, keywords):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046558/190597 (piRSquared)
    """
    v = ser.values.astype(str)
    # >>> (np.core.defchararray.find(v[:, None], columns) >= 0)
    # array([[ True, False,  True, False],
    #        [False,  True,  True, False],
    #        [ True, False, False,  True],
    #        [False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

    result = pd.DataFrame(
        (np.core.defchararray.find(v[:, None], keywords) >= 0).astype(int),
        index=ser.index, columns=keywords)
    return result

def using_extractall(ser, keywords):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046417/190597 (unutbu)
    """
    pat = '|'.join(['({})'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in keywords])
    result = (ser.str.extractall(pat)).groupby(level=0).count()
    result.columns = keywords
    return result

def using_contains(ser, keywords):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046142/190597 (cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ)
    """
    return (pd.concat([ser.str.contains(x) for x in keywords], 
                      axis=1, keys=keywords).astype(int))

def make_random_str_array(letters=string.ascii_letters, strlen=10, size=100):
    return (np.random.choice(list(letters), size*strlen)
            .view('|U{}'.format(strlen)))

keywords = make_random_str_array(size=99)
arr = np.random.choice(keywords, size=(1000, 5),replace=True)
ser = pd.Series([' '.join(row) for row in arr])
```

Be sure to check benchmarks on your own machine, and with a setup similar to your use case. Results may vary due to numerous factors, such as size of the Series, `ser`, length of `keywords`, hardware, OS, version of NumPy, Pandas, and Python, and how they were compiled.

Comment: Nice answer :-)

Answer (score 7):

Use [**`numpy.core.defchararray.find`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.find.html) and `numpy` braodcasting

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

v = df['labels'].values.astype(str)
l = ['created','tower','destroyed','swimming pool']

pd.DataFrame(
    (find(v[:, None], l) >= 0).astype(int),
    df.index, l
)

       created  tower  destroyed  swimming pool
index                                          
1            1      1          0              0
2            0      1          1              0
3            1      0          0              1
4            0      0          1              1
```

---

`find` will broadcast the `str.find` function across the dimensions of string arrays we provide.  `find` returns the position in the string from the first array that the string from the second is first found.  If it isn't found, it returns `-1`.  Because of this, we can evaluate if the string is found by evaluating if the return value of `find` is greater than or equal to `0`.

Comment: vote for the speed !!!, I will using this one for my stacking model ! :)

Comment: Thanks @Wen! In my opinion, this is more intuitive and elegant as well.  It vectorizes the looping nicely.

Comment: @piRSquared : This is awesome. In my benchmarking, your solution seems to be fastest. How about inverse transformation? multiple columns to single column (ignoring 'the')

Comment: @GKS if this answer did it for you, you could consider accepting it and asking a new question. Inverse transformation seems like an unrelated problem... I think it'd be cool to open a separate question!

Answer (score 4):

In your case, if the break words is `the` you can just using following to achieve it.  (PS: It is better for you to using COLDSPEED's answer when the break word not only `The`)

```
pd.get_dummies(df['labels'].str.split('the').apply(pd.Series))

Out[424]: 
   0_created   0_destroyed   1_ swimming pool  1_ tower
0           1             0                 0         1
1           0             1                 0         1
2           1             0                 1         0
3           0             1                 1         0
```

Comment: Interesting approach... I didn't consider using `the`. I think .apply(pd.Series) is slow but you can speed it up by using the constructor `pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df['labels'].str.split('the').values.tolist()))` Should be twice as fast now.

Comment: @Wen : Nice solution. But 'the' is not the only break word

Comment: @GKS then you can look at other genius' answer, also , their answer is much faster :)

Comment: I did. I did some quick benchmarking, and the one by @piRSquared looks the fastest. Will wait for other comments before accepting it

Comment: @GKS Might want to look at unutbu's benchmarks too.